# creating WCF and hosting it on IIS

Tags: c#, wcf, https

i have seen alot of questions and tutorials about this subject but none of them seem to fully answer my questions. 
Im am doing a 3 layers project. I have service library called ServiceHandlers which gets data from microsoft ax 2012 and putts the right entity on it. Then i have a wcf service called Services which calls these get functions from the serviceHandlers (has a reference to that project) .. and then in the end of there is the client side which can be winform,console or whatever. My questions is that my boss wants me to put the services on up on a localserver with HTTPS communication. Now this would be easy if i only had the service and client part. I would just folllows this tutorial http://debugmode.net/2010/09/07/walkthrough-on-creating-wcf-4-0-service-and-hosting-in-iis-7-5/ ) .. but since i have the serviceHandler part also everything seems a mess. What should i do ?? MY boss is on a vacation and i have no one to ask  so i now little as nothing

Comment: If the service references a deplendency (ServiceHandlers.dll), then that doesn't sound like a problem.  Just bin deploy the dependency.

Comment: i the tutorials i have seen there i basicly no logic in the .svc file of the wcf service , just a one liner the service"servicelibrary.services" thing .. in my case there is some logic in the wcf service project , doesnt that make any difference

Comment: the .svc usually has a 'code-behind' .svc.cs that sits behind.  However, no, it shouldn't make a difference.

Answer (score 0):

If you need standalone WCF service you can follow this tutorial: [How to: Host a WCF service in IIS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx). Actually you need to create

- `/App_code` folder with real C# code file (just like this copy/paste cs file there)
- `/bin` folder with all your .DLL files. You need an already working program with all dependencies resolved (don't forget to include: System.ServiceModel). The project itslef you can build from WCF Service Library template from VS and just reference your other projects/libs/resources (**don't forget to copy them with your project .dll file**)
- In main 'VirtualFolder' (that already converted to Application in IIS) put the .svc file and web.config file. SVC file build as follows:

  <@ServiceHost language="C#" *Debug="true"* Service="full-name-including-namespace-to-class-that-implements-interface" @>

  Hopefully this will work from the begining. *There's zillions a possible combination of what could go wrong, strange errors and just-dead situations - I just could not explain about all of them* In case you run into another problem you could search this site for solution